# div popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am doing wrong?
When you click on class divtop, it should show a div popup in the middle of the page. At that time back page should become not clickable. escape or a button in popup will close it.

```
<html lang="en" class=" en">
<head>
    <title>My Test Popup</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .divtop
        {
            width: 800px; 
            height: 300px; 
            border:solid;
        }

        .divbottom
        {
            top: 400px; 
        }

        .localmenu {
            border: 1px solid black;
            background: #fff;
            margin-left : auto;
            top: 50px; width: 300px; 
            padding-top: 25px; 
            margin-top: 100px; 
            height: 150px;
        }

        .appContent{
            width: 800px; 
            border:solid;
            height: 600px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .maincontent{
            width: 100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="appContent" >
        <div class="maincontent" >
            <div class="divtop" >Top</div>
            <div class="divtop divbottom"  >Bottom</div>
        </div>
        <div id="popup" style="width : 100%; height: 600px;display: none;">
            <div class='localmenu'>
                Text in Div Popup<br/>                        
                <button id="btnHide">Close</button><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.divtop').click(function() {
                $('#popup').show().css("top", "500px").animate({top: 50}, 200);
                $('.mainContent').css("background-color", "grey");
            });

            $('#btnHide').click(function() {
                $('#popup').hide();
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: You have `display:none` in the CSS for `.localmenu` so naturally it won't be visible.

Comment: You could simply use the blockui plugin. It will handle this and more for all sorts of browsers.

Comment: display:none helps with display. How can I make it in center pf page of back div not clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QgFWX/)

I added some CSS to your #popup and it's now all in the CSS (not inline in the html). Changed also your jQuery animate to 50px, instead of just 50.
I think you have small adjustments to do to the CSS, like in `.localmenu` I'm not sure why you have both `padding-top: 25px; margin-top: 100px;`.

CSS

```
#popup {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left:30%;
    z-index:1;
}
#popoverlay {
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.divtop').click(function () {
        $('#popoverlay').show();
        $('#popup').show().css("top", "500px").animate({
            top: "50px"
        }, 200);
        $('.mainContent').css("background-color", "grey");
    });

    $('#btnHide').click(function () {
        $('#popup').hide();
        $('#popoverlay').hide();
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="appContent">
    <div class="maincontent">
        <div class="divtop">Top</div>
        <div class="divtop divbottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <div class='localmenu'>Text in Div Popup
            <br/>
            <button id="btnHide">Close</button>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. This helps. to be clear, "position:absolute" is the main difference. right? Also - how do I make other div non clickable?

Comment: @AjayBansal, just edited my answer, now with overlay div also.

Comment: Thank you. Added useful. Also handled Escape key now. Only thing that needs to be done is ignore clicks when popup div is visible. How do i achieve that?

Comment: @AjayBansal, ignore clicks where? under the grey overlay?

Answer (score 1):

#### To block the div tags at the back from being clickable:

Add a div with the following style in your HTML. Im gonna call it `overlay`.

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: none;
}
```

This will essentially cover up your page when shown up.

#### To center your popup:

I added some extra styles to `#popup` and removed some from `.localmenu`. You were missing `position: absolute` and `z-index`, added those in. (`z-index` of `popup` must be > `z-index` of `overlay`)

```
#popup {    
    background: #fff;
    position :absolute;
    left : 40%;
    width : 300px;
    height: 600px;    
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10001;
}

.localmenu
{
  border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Then, in your JS,

- In your `animate` method, I changed `50px` to `30%` to center `div#popup`
- Added code to hide and show `.overlay` along with `#popup`.

After the changes,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.divtop').click(function () {
         $('#popup').show().css("top", "500px").animate({
             top: "30%"
         }, 200);
         $('.overlay').show();
     });

     $('#btnHide').click(function () {
         $('#popup,.overlay').hide();
     });

 });
```

#### Demo

http://jsbin.com/olasog/1

#### Code

http://jsbin.com/olasog/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work properly, even if there is a vertical scroll bar, you have to use position "fixed". Place `popup` as a direct child of `body` and make it's `position: fixed`, and `width` and `height` 100%. Place `localmenu` as a direct child of `body` as well. Working example at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oyutoc/1/).

Html:

```
<div id="popup">
  <!--// This is to stop the user from interacting with the content in the back
      // and to give a visual clue about that
  -->
</div>
<div class='localmenu'>
  <div>
    Text in Div Popup<br/>                        
    <button id="btnHide">Close</button><br/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="appContent" >
  <div class="maincontent" >
    <div class="divtop" >Top</div>
    <div class="divtop divbottom"  >Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  //Use opacity to give a visual clue. Please note that this doesn't work in -all- browsers
  #popup {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    background: black;
    opacity: .5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  //This is just to be able to center the actual menu
    .localmenu {
        top: 20%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        height: 150px;
        display: none;
    }

  .localmenu > div {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background: #fff;
        margin-left : auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
  }
```

Javascript: (This is mostly the same, although I removed the animate, because I don't know exactly how it works and it needs to end at `'top: 0'`. As localmenu and popup are seperate, we show them seperate as well.)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.divtop').click(function() {
            $('#popup').show().animate(200);
            $('.localmenu').show();
            //$('.mainContent').css("background-color", "grey");
        });

        $('#btnHide').click(function() {
            $('#popup').hide();
            $('.localmenu').hide();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.divtop').click(function() {
        var div = $('.appContent');
        $('.localmenu').css({'margin': '200px auto'});
        $('#popup').show().css({top: "500px", position: 'absolute', width: div.width(), height: div.height()}).animate({top: 0}, 200);
        $('.mainContent').css("background-color", "grey");
    });

    $('#btnHide').click(function() {
        $('.mainContent').css("background-color", "");
        $('#popup').hide();
    });
});
```